# Performance of eigen value determination using MKL library

Tags: c++, matrix, eigenvalue, intel-mkl, eigenvector

My objective is to find Eigen values and vectors of an input matrix of `mxn` size. Since it a rectangular matrix, converted the same to square-symmetric matrix by doing a ***transpose*** and then ***matrix-multiplication with source*** matrix.

After this, i am using Intel MKL library to determine Eigen values and vectors of square-symmetric matrix. Unfortunately, for square symmetric matrix size of `1000000 x 100000` the time taken is ~35 to ~40 secs, which does not suit my application.

Any suggestions on improving the performance would be really helpful.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Computing eigenvalues of big matrices just is expensive. You either modify your algorithm to not need the eigenvalues or to produce matrices whose eigenvalues are easier to compute or you pay the runtime price to find the eigenvalues. No way around that.

Answer (score 0):

Large eigenvalue problems are expensive. I'd suggest using the FEAST eigenvalue solver, which is available via the MKL library. I think that FEAST 3.0 is not available with MKL, but you can [download](http://www.ecs.umass.edu/~polizzi/feast/) and compile it separately.

It offers a tunable search space, if you only need a subset of Eigen pairs, and distributed/threaded parallelization.